# Capturing CPU and Memory logs from command line

Tags: ios, memory-management, terminal, instruments, trace

I need to capture CPU and Memory usage of iOS app running on device. Basically i need to profile iOS apps from command line and save the data to a readable file format.

I tried:

1. instruments -t '/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/Allocations.tracetemplate' -w 'Device UDID' /path/myApp.app

but it gives error that the trace template does not exist. However it exists at the path when i go to it manually.

2. iprofiler -allocations

It also gives error: iprofiler error: Allocations instrument requires single process or pid to be specified

How can i get pid of the app currently running on device.

3. idevicesyslog

It only gives some unuseful info but no CPU/Memory usage data.

**EDIT**

Now that i am able to capture information but the output is a .trace file which is an instruments file. Is there any way i can parse/read the .trace file and convert it to a csv/excel file through command line?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am working on the same problem and this would help.

Comment: If you are able to capture CPU/Memory data, you can use https://github.com/zijie0/AMParser to read the Activity monitor trace file.

Comment: @Assassin how did you get the CPU / Memory data? Using Instruments?